# Spring Framework under high load with @Async methods

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, asynchronous

I am building highly available & scalable web application. It will also handle quite significant load.

The question is, how `@Async` methods work in Spring Framework?

I am planning to use`@Async` method for the logging ( send the logs to some external logging server ). And I wonder how the system will behave if a lot of threads ( ie users ) will start to call these methods?

As far as I understand Spring takes pre-created threads from the thread's executor.
But what happen, if there are only 3 threads, but 1000 simultaneous users?

Will `@Async` method be blocked, unless some thread become available and start doing the job?
Or the "job" will be placed in queue and the main thread will continue to run as expected?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `@Async` documentation can be found here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support)

In short, to get `@Async` to work, you need to declare an `Executor`. This `Executor` will be responsible for executing your `@Async` annotated method.

In a typical application, you would declare a thread pool backed `Executor`.

When you invoke your `@Async` method, a proxy will intercept the invocation, create a `Runnable` (or `Callable`) and submit it to the `Executor`. It will then return immediately. So the call to the `@Async` method is never blocking.

However, if your `Executor` doesn't have any available threads, ie. they are all busy executing other submitted tasks, the `@Async` task you submitted will remain in a queue until a thread becomes available.